# ゲームクリア後のリスタート時に、カードをシャッフルして再表示したい。

Tags: java, swing

Java swingを使用して、神経衰弱を作成しています。
以下のソースコードにて、ゲームクリア後のリスタート時に、カードをシャッフルして再表示したいのですが`Collections.shuffle(cards);`を使用してもシャッフルされていませんでした。
※ゲーム起動時はシャッフルされているのは確認しております。

```
    // Restart時にカードを裏面にする
public void Restart_cards() {
    Collections.shuffle(cards);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
        cards.get(i).setOpen(flg);
    }

}
```

また、以下を追加してみたのですがリスタートを行ってもシャッフルされませんでした。

```
for(CardLabel card_shuffle : cards) {
        add(card_shuffle);
    }
```

お手数ですが、その他記載方法等をご教示いただけますと幸いです。

**CardList.java**

```
package pair_matching;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CardList extends JPanel{
    private GameDate gameDate = new GameDate();
    JButton reset_btn;
    
    // ラベルをリストにする -> リストの各ラベルにImageIconをセット -> リストをコレクションシャッフル
    boolean flg = false;
    
    final int club = 0;
    final int diamond = 1;
    final int heart = 2;
    final int spade = 3;
    
    /* カード画像 */
    // 裏面
    ImageIcon card_back = new ImageIcon("image/card_back.png");
    // 表面
    ImageIcon[][] card_array = new ImageIcon[4][13];
    String filename;
    
    // jの数値
    int[] number = {
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
    };
    
    // カードをリスト化
    ArrayList<CardLabel> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public CardList() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1150, 600));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 13));
        Start_card_list();
    }
    
    public void Start_card_list() {
        // Card_image
        for(int i = 0; i < card_array.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < card_array[i].length; j++) {
                filename = "image/card";
                switch(i) {
                case club:
                    filename = filename + "_club_";
                    break;
                case diamond:
                    filename = filename + "_diamond_";
                    break;
                case heart:
                    filename = filename + "_heart_";
                    break;
                case spade:
                    filename = filename + "_spade_";
                    break;
                }
                // ファイル名に数字を足す -> 拡張子を足す
                filename = String.format(filename + "%02d", j+1);
                filename = filename + ".png";
                card_array[i][j] = new ImageIcon(filename);
                CardLabel tmp_label = new CardLabel(card_array[i][j],card_back,number[j]);
                // tmp_labelを押下したら、ひっくり返るのはtmp_label
                tmp_label.addMouseListener(new Cardclick_Listener(tmp_label, gameDate, this));
                add(tmp_label);
                cards.add(tmp_label);
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
        // カードのシャッフル
        for(CardLabel card_shuffle : cards) {
            add(card_shuffle);
        }
    }
    
    // Restart時にカードを裏面にする
    public void Restart_cards() {
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
            cards.get(i).setOpen(flg);
        }

    }
}
```

**Cardclick_Listener.java**

```
package pair_matching;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Cardclick_Listener implements MouseListener{
    private CardLabel card_label;
    private GameDate gameDate;
    private CardList cardList;
    
    public Cardclick_Listener(CardLabel card_label, GameDate gameDate, CardList cardList) {
        this.card_label = card_label;
        this.gameDate = gameDate;
        this.cardList = cardList;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        boolean open = card_label.isOpen();
        int Pair = gameDate.getPairCount();
        
        // カードの表裏チェック
        if(open == true) {
            return; // 裏面にしない
        }else if(open == false){
            card_label.setOpen(true);
            if(gameDate.getCard_one() == null) {
                // nullの場合：GameDateのCard_oneに格納
                gameDate.setCard_one(card_label);
                return;
            }else{
                // null以外:GameDateのCard_twoに格納
                gameDate.setCard_two(card_label);
            }
        }
    
        /* ペア成立 */
        if(gameDate.getCard_two().getNumber() == gameDate.getCard_one().getNumber()) {
            if(open == true) {
                gameDate.setPairCount(Pair += 0); // 表のカードを押下した時に2がカウントされないようにする
            }else {
                /* ゲームクリアの条件
                 * 52枚揃ったらクリア
                 * */
                gameDate.setPairCount(Pair += 2); // 枚数のカウント
                gameDate.setCard_one(null); // Card_oneをリセット
                gameDate.setCard_two(null); // Card_twoをリセット
                
                if(Pair == 52) {
                    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "GAME CREA!!! 「はい」を押下でゲームを再開できます。", "GAME CREA", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    if(option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        cardList.Restart_cards(); // カードを全て裏面にする
                        gameDate.setPairCount(0); // 枚数カウントのリセット
                    }else {
                        System.exit(0); // ゲーム終了
                    }
                }
            }
            /* ペア不成立 */
        }else{
            /*
             *cardListのrevers_btnを活性化させる処理を追加
             *cardListのrevers_btnを押下した時の処理をrevers_button_clickに追加
             * */
            
            int missmatch = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "カードが一致しませんでした。", "カードの不一致", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            if(missmatch == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                gameDate.getCard_one().setOpen(false);
                gameDate.getCard_two().setOpen(false);
                gameDate.setCard_one(null); // Card_oneをリセット
                gameDate.setCard_two(null); // Card_twoをリセット
            }else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ご質問の中で追加されたコードのうち、前者は「カードを裏面にする」処理です。
後者は「既にカード配置済みのパネルにカードを追加する処理」です。
`ArrayList<CardLabel> cards`はゲーム内部の変数なので、CardListパネルの子要素(CardLabel)を**クリアして再配布**しないとシャッフルが適用されません。

子要素をクリアするには[`removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#removeAll--)を使用します。
これはswingの特性ですが、単一メソッドの中で`removeAll`した後に`add`しても中身が書き換わりません。
[パネルの中身を書き換える](http://bb-biz.com/java-desktop-schedule-030/)ためには`removeAll`の後に`revalidate`と`repaint`を呼び出して子要素のクリアを反映させてください。

```
// Restart時にカードを裏面にするだけでなく
// Restart時にカードを再配布する
public void Restart_cards() {
    // 裏面にする処理(これはこれで必要)
    for(int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
        cards.get(i).setOpen(false);
    }
    // 再配布する処理(Collections.shuffleした後に再配布しないとカードの位置は変わらない)
    // カードをすべて除去
    removeAll();
    // カードの除去をCardListに適用して再描画
    revalidate();
    repaint();    // 再描画をせずとも今回は問題ないけれどおまじない
    // シャッフル
    Collections.shuffle(cards);
    // 再配布
    for(CardLabel card_shuffle : cards) {
        add(card_shuffle);
    }
}
```